# What Is The OAuth2 Authorization Flow For An External Provider-Protected App To Access An IdentityServer4 Protected API?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have found samples for using IS4 with an external provider, but none that include an API that belongs to IS4 so I need to understand how it actually works first.

The scenario is this:-

[ API + IS4 ] in one network

[ App + Okta Auth ] in another network, completely separate

The user logs on to the app using their creds managed by Okta.
At some point during the session, they make a call to the API to get some data.

I thought that the idea was to create a trust between IS4 and Okta so that the same token generated by Okta could be used to access the API. However, the more I read up, I think I have made that up in my head or maybe confused it with something completely different! The reason being I found an article that said the API can't use a token from another identity provider and that some sort of token swap goes on.

Can someone explain what the flow is in this scenario?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The app in the other network would call its own back end, which is protected by Okta tokens. That back end would then authenticate with IS4, using the client credentials flow, before calling the IS4 protected API.

This is how most B2B solutions across companies (or divisions) work. Each company has their own Authorization Server hosted next to their APIs.

Comment: hi gary, i'm not sure i understand what the "back end" is that you're referring to - is it the okta server? or is it like a custom service proxy to make the call to the api on behalf of the app? if it's using client creds then i think that means the back end needs a standard client secret for auth with IS4 and so this wouldn't be an external provider scenario, is that right?